# Rails - How can I have an if statement in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rails-models

I have the carrierwave gem installed for image uploads. I need to apply `mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader` to `values` with the `value_type` equal to `3`. Here is what I've tried.

The code below doesn't throw any errors it also doesn't seem to make any difference as if the if statement it isn't there.

```
mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader, if: 'value_type == 3'
```

I tried the code below which works for non image types (anything with a `value_type` other than 3) but saves the images as `#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe74b2e2e28>` instead of `image-name.png`

```
if :value_type == 3
mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader
else
end
```

And I also tried this which also is ignored like the first attempt as if the if condition isnt even applied

```
mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader, if: :image?

 def image?
    self.value_type == 3
 end
```

By its self without any if statement `mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader` saves images just fine but any other value type doesnt save (such as text), the if statement should fix this. I dont know why the second option doesnt work but I'm sure its some random reason that is out of my scope of knowledge on rails. I'm really hoping someone here will have a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should use a block:

```
mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader, if: proc { |o| o.value_type == 3 }
```

where `o` is an instance of a model.

But the proper way to use a signle field for various purposes is to use [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html), so you will have a single parent class for a table, and subclasses for various cases:

**app/models/base_model.rb**:

```
class BaseModel < AR::Base
end
```

**app/models/base_models/pic.rb**:

```
class Pic < BaseModel
   mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader # value as an image
end
```

**app/models/base_models/text.rb**:

```
class Text < BaseModel
   # value as a string
end
```

**Note** that you have to add the `type` field to the `base_models` table.

Comment: I tried adding `, if: proc { |o| o.value_type == 3 }` but it did nothing (same as the first and third try I had). I need it because I have `items` that have values, these values can vary on what info they hold such as long slabs of text, one or two words, links etc..(`value_type` holds what type of value it is) I'm adding the ability for images to be uploaded for an item as a value, If I make a whole new column just for it it would cause a lot of core coding changes so I'm seeing if it is possible to go down this path instead

Comment: Its too late to implement STI at this point unfortunately, I would have to start over with a lot of coding. Do you know the reason why `, if: proc { |o| o.value_type == 3 }` doesn't work? or my other methods dont work. It would be nice to know the reason it isnt working so I know if its a dead end or if there is hope.

Comment: The reason why the _if_ option doesn't work is explained in my answer. It doesn't matter what value/proc you pass to the _if_, the method `mount_uploader` does not use it. I would second the opinion of @МалъСкрылевъ on the use of STI.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any reference to an *if:* option on the *mount_uploader* method documentation at:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/Mount:mount_uploader

Neither is it mentioned in the source for the latest stable version (0.11):

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/17ae595237339ea9372aa4b9144387c5041b32f0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb

Are you sure you're not mixing it up with the CarrierWave::Uploader::Versions::ClassMethods#version method that does support that?

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/Uploader/Versions/ClassMethods#version-instance_method

Comment: Yea I checked if they had anything but they diddnt. Thats why I'm trying to do it in the model in a way thats unrelated to the models carrierwave have.